# ggplot2 show legends with geom_abline and geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate legends for geom_smooth and geom_abline using the following code

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = log(x), y =log(y) )) +
  geom_hex() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=y~x, color = "red", show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_abline(color = "green", show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='Lines', values=c("Regression", "Abline"))+
  theme_bw()
```

I have seen a related question here: [ggplot2 legend for abline and stat_smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844161/ggplot2-legend-for-abline-and-stat-smooth), but none of the recommended solutions generate a legend.  Any ideas?

Some fake data:

```
x <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
y <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
d <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
```

EDIT: Following Camile's suggestion, I added aes() wrapping around the colors, but to no avail.

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = log(x), y =log(y) )) +
  geom_hex() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=y~x, aes(color = "red"), show.legend=TRUE) +
  geom_abline(aes(color = "green"), show.legend=TRUE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='Lines', values=c("Regression", "Abline"))+
  theme_bw()
```

This works for the geom_smooth line, but now geom_abline is saying: "Error: geom_abline requires the following missing aesthetics: slope, intercept"

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `color` in your `aes`. Even if it's just a dummy assignment, there has to be something inside an `aes`

Comment: What you give as values to `scale_color_manual` should be names or hex codes of colors, not the names of groups. Also, `geom_abline` requires a slope and intercept, which you haven't set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an option

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = log(x), y =log(y) )) +
  geom_hex() +
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=y~x, aes(color = "red")) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0, color = "green"), show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='Lines',
                      labels = c("Abline", "Regression"), 
                      values=c("green", "red")) +
  theme_bw()
```

When we map `color` to `"green"` inside `geom_abline` `ggplot` complained

> error: geom_abline requires the following missing aesthetics: slope, intercept

That's why I had to include these aesthetics too.

[image]

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you!  For some reason, in my real data, the legend has a slash through the line.  Do you have any sense for what that is?

Comment: I saw that too. Did you include `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_abline` ?

Comment: Nice! that did it.  What a weird glitch